# How To Use Embedding To Get Data From A Table

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am a PHP programmer and I have just learned Golang for weeks. I am writing REST API to get `post` information from my 'posts' table. I have the `FindPostByID` method in `posts_controller`. This controller uses `Post` struct which is model

```
func (p *Post) FindPostByID(db *gorm.DB, pid uint64) (*Post, error) {
    var err error
    err = db.Debug().Model(&Post{}).Where("id = ?", pid).Take(&p).Error
    if err != nil {
        return &Post{}, err
    }
    if p.ID != 0 {
        err = db.Debug().Model(&User{}).Where("id = ?", p.AuthorID).Take(&p.Author).Error
        if err != nil {
            return &Post{}, err
        }
    }
    return p, nil
}
```

But now I want to add method `FindByID` into parent struct, such as `ParentModel` because when I have `articles_controller` I can use `FindByID` method in parent struct to get an article info. So I have the following code in parent struct

```
type ParentModel struct {
    
}

func (m *ParentModel) FindByID(db *gorm.DB, uid uint64) (*ParentModel, error) {
    var err error
    err = db.Debug().Model(ParentModel{}).Where("id = ?", uid).Take(&m).Error
    if err != nil {
        return &ParentModel{}, err
    }
    if gorm.IsRecordNotFoundError(err) {
        return &ParentModel{}, errors.New("User Not Found")
    }
    return m, err
}
```

And I change in the `Post` struct like following:

```
type Post struct {
    ParentModel
    ID        uint64    `gorm:"primary_key;auto_increment" json:"id"`
    Title     string    `gorm:"size:255;not null;unique" json:"title"`
    Content   string    `gorm:"size:255;not null;" json:"content"`
    Author    User      `json:"author"`
    AuthorID  uint32    `sql:"type:int REFERENCES users(id)" json:"author_id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"updated_at"`
}
```

I change `FindPostByID` method in `posts_controller` as well:

```
func (server *Server) GetPost(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    pid, err := strconv.ParseUint(vars["id"], 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        responses.ERROR(w, http.StatusBadRequest, err)
        return
    }
    post := models.Post{}

    postReceived, err := post.FindByID(server.DB, pid)
    if err != nil {
        responses.ERROR(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
        return
    }
    responses.JSON(w, http.StatusOK, postReceived)
}
```

When I run my program, have the err: `Table 'golang_rest_api.parent_models' doesn't exist`.

How I can do to use inheritance method like PHP language

Comment: *"How I can do to use inheritance method like PHP language"* Go does not have inheritance. Embedding does not change the receiver of the embedded method, it just "promotes" it, which allows you to invoke it without explicitly qualifying it with the field name. `post.FindByID` is just "syntactic sugar" for `post.ParentModel.FindByID`.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#inheritance - my advice: when you write code in go, you need to suspend the inheritance-based design mindset. The earlier you do, the less painful your experience will be.

Comment: Thanks for your advance. So I have to define method in each controller to get data from corresponding model, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The error `Table 'golang_rest_api.parent_models' doesn't exist` means that no table named `parent_models` exists in your database.

This is because `gorm` by default uses the pluralised camelcase name of your struct, which you supplied in gorm's `Model()` method, as its table's name.

Gorm provides in-built support for many kinds of associations which you can find [here](https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html). I would also like to ask you to complete your `ParentModel` struct's definition. It's empty right now.